# No route matches stylesheets/stylesheet.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While starting the Rails server it's giving me the below error:

```
ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. @ io_f illbuf - fd:6

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches[GET]"/stylesheets/stylesheet.css"):
```

Thank you.

Comment: Seems you're trying to include the css file manually? The path should be "/assets/stylesheets/stylesheet.css"

Try update your template to include it with this in the href attribute: <%= asset_path 'stylesheets/stylesheet.css' %>

Comment: I didn't try to include the css and javascript file.i already install the gem file. Javascript not working properly,due this effect  dropdown button doesn't work properly.

Comment: This looks like a problem with something inside your system. You shouldn't also be calling `stylesheets/stylesheet.css` directly - you need to use `asset_path(stylesheet.css)`